# Oculus quest 2 controller models do not properly loaded in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, oculusquest

When I am using my Oculus Quest 2 on `https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/laser-controls/` the Oculus Quest **1** controller models are loaded rather the Quest **2**.

Is there any native solution to load the correct ones?

I have also tried the tag `<a-entity oculus-touch-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>` without success.

Comment: This is very strange.  I'm also testing with an Oculus Quest 2, and various pages that used to correctly display the Oculus Quest 2 controllers are now all showing Quest 1 controllers.

This includes pages that use A-Frame versions from 1.1.0 to the very latest A-Frame code.

I don't yet know what has changed to cause this.

Comment: Controller models here look correct (i.e. model 2):
https://cdn.aframe.io/controllers/oculus/oculus-touch-controller-left.gltf
https://cdn.aframe.io/controllers/oculus/oculus-touch-controller-right.gltf

(viewed using https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)

Comment: Ah - the ones I am seeing are in fact these ones...
https://cdn.aframe.io/controllers/oculus/oculus-touch-controller-gen2-left.gltf

These were added under this change on 31 Oct 2021.
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/commit/4705cda1cb8bfab5219da6fab78c8825047996bb

It looks to me like as part of this change, the 1st gen & 2nd gen controller models have been swapped over in the A-Frame CDN.

Answer (score 0):

I have raised this issue (with more details) to try to get this resolved.
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4960

Seems that recently the Oculus Quest 2 has started reporting something different on the WebXR API, which means it appears to have Quest 1 controllers.  This affects not only A-Frame but also Babylon.js and the Firefox Reality broswer.

If you wanted to fix in the very short term, you could make a code change in A-Frame:

In oculus-touch-controls replace this line:

```
modelUrl: TOUCH_CONTROLLER_MODEL_BASE_URL + 'gen2-left.gltf',
```

with this:

```
modelUrl: TOUCH_CONTROLLER_MODEL_BASE_URL + 'v3-left.glb',
```

But this is a hacky workaround for something that Meta should really be fixing on the device firmware (as it seems they broke it)

I am hoping that the A-Frame Devs are able to help drive this forward with Meta.  I have raised an Oculus support ticket, but no word on that yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But my controllers look like [link](https://www.turbosquid.com/fr/3d-models/oculus-quest-2-controller-3d-model-1651123) which are not the same as 'gen2-left.gltf', nor 'left.gltf'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look closely enough at the white one.

This is the one you want:
https://cdn.aframe.io/controllers/oculus/oculus-touch-controller-v3-left.glb

The models are even more mixed up than I had thought - I will update the github issue.

Comment: And the temporary workaround would be:

modelUrl: TOUCH_CONTROLLER_MODEL_BASE_URL + 'v3-left.glb',

Comment: Update from the GitHub issue - looks like the CDN links are in fact correct, so the next most likely explanation is that both your & my Quest 2 have started reporting themselves as a Quest 1 on the WebXR profile id.

Comment: I updated my answer above to reflect the latest understanding from the Aframe issue (linked above)

Comment: Thanks for the explanations @diarmid-mackenzie
Following them, I tried 2 things by changing the `oculus-touch-controls.js` file:

1. I changed: `var CONTROLLER_DEFAULT = 'oculus-touch';` to `var CONTROLLER_DEFAULT = 'oculus-touch-v3';`

2. I filled `var CONTROLLER_PROPERTIES = {
  'oculus-touch':` with the same content as `oculus-touch-v3':`

Both solutions do not work. I should miss something. Is there a simple solution or should I use a `custom-controls` entity?

Comment: Latest on this issue is that Facebook have acknowledged it as a bug, and will be fixing in the next version of Oculus Browser.  I don't have a date for that.

In the meantime, if you want to fix, you can use the fix here:
https://github.com/diarmidmackenzie/aframe/blob/oculus-touch-fix/src/components/oculus-touch-controls.js

Comment: It won't be here forever, but for now it's available on my github pages:  e.g.
https://diarmidmackenzie.github.io/aframe/examples/test/laser-controls/index.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending time to answer me.
The last link work with the good 3D model but there is a wrong X rotation compare to the reality.

Comment: I have test the [laser controls page](https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/test/laser-controls/) with a colleague's Quest 2 and it works. His config: Version Browser: 17.4, Version: 33, Version d'exécution: 33. My config (the Quest 2 which does not load the appropriate controller model): Version Browser: 17.2, Version: 34, Version d'exécution: 34.
The problem might be due to the browser version, which is consistent with what was said in the previous message. The point is that the Oculus OS don't propose me an update.
Well, I will use the colleague's Quest 2 while waiting a new version.