# Oculus controllers are black with A-frame

Tags: aframe

11-21-2021 I have been testing oculus quest 2 controllers with A-frame.
They were white in color but last night the suddenly changed to black? Why?

Answer (score 0):

See:
[Oculus quest 2 controller models do not properly loaded in A-Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69914097/oculus-quest-2-controller-models-do-not-properly-loaded-in-a-frame/69931784#69931784)

Latest is in this GitHub issue:
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/4960

Seems to be an issue with the Oculus Quest 2 itself reporting the wrong profile.

Affects A-Frame, Babylon.js and Firefox Reality Browser environment (and probably som other things too).